# Users want to help to solve bugs - but the questions are put on hold. Please help

Tags: support

This question
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227842/how-to-hide-userdata-of-deleted-users-in-reply-module
is about a bug in the reply module.

I am very sure that stackexchange users want to help to solve this bug. But some moderates like Clive put such questions on hold and delete the questions later.

Please make it possible to re-activate this question and let stackexchange users to help. The patch may have only 5 or 10 lines.

This is ideal for a format like "Drupal Answers" to be discussed and solved here.

Please re-enable the question. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to say, but I think you're asking the wrong question, maybe because you've not enough experience in using this drupal.SE site. Have a look at the answers to http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2561/ , to understand the "opinions" from some long term users (not mine) about the kind of bug-related questions that might fit on this site. It's your choice, but I really recommend you to try to learn some of the basic rules of this site. Specific to questions about "bugs", I have learned that most of them are not allowed on this site. See you on D.O ... in "your issue"!

Answer (score 4):

No.

As you are already well aware from the comments, questions about bug reports and their workarounds are off topic here.

The question will not be reopened, and if you keep spamming people in the comments further action will be taken.

This is a community moderated site, and the community have decided they do not want this type of question here.

Please show some respect.

For your reference: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic